# How to get the two last part of string separated by ,

Tags: c#, string

I have some strings in C# like this:

```
interesting, fun, May 08, 2012
this is very interesting text, June 19, 2011
```

I'd like to get 2 strings, one with date and the other with all the string

So the output should be like this:

```
string1=interesting, fun
string2=May 08, 2012

string1=this is very interesting text
string2=June 19, 2011
```

Appreciate any hint.

Comment: What exactly is "blah"? and how many ',' do you have?

Comment: can be any string like "Easy to read, steeped in experience, immediately practical" or even one word . The number of them are unknown

Comment: The date will always have one comma?  So is it safe to assume that the second comma from the end is your separator?

Comment: yeah, it is like that format always

Comment: @MT467 You need to identify the format clearly and what are the delimiters. Is something like this valid for example "May 08, June 09, April 12, 2012, 2013"?

Comment: In what way have you had no success with split, substring and lastindexof? Did it successfully split it into parts on the comma, and you're just not sure how to combine them again? Or did split, substring and lastindexof actually not react to the comma?

Comment: @nmat it is only one date in the string

Comment: @JonathanHobbs I tried combination of them, if you have anything in your mind please share with me, I can try at no harm

Comment: @MT467 Ok, but like I asked - what were the results of using them? Why didn't they work?

Comment: just wondering why they close the topic?? people edited my original question and changed it to something else???!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I know there's totally a better way than this (such as with Regex), but here's a quick and dirty way:

```
string str1 = "blah, blah, May 08, 2012";
string str2 = "blah blah blah, June 19, 2011";

int splitter = str1.Substring(0, str1.LastIndexOf(',')).LastIndexOf(',');

string newStr1 = str1.Substring(0, splitter);
string newStr2 = str1.Substring(splitter + 2, str1.Length - (splitter + 2));

Console.WriteLine(newStr1);
Console.WriteLine(newStr2);

Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Am I the only one here seeing: "blah, blah, May 08, blah blah, 2012" in the original post? If so, you can't assume that format.

Comment: Refresh. I updated his post.  That's TWO lines of text.

Comment: Great! works like a charm, Tnx

Answer (score 0):

```
bool foundDateComma = false;
string beginning, date;
for (int i = s.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    if (s[i] == ',')
        if (!foundDateComma)
            foundDateComma = true;
        else
        {
            beginning = s.Substring(0, i);
            date = s.Substring(i + 1);
            break;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Regular expression could help you:

```
Match match = Regex.Match(yourstring, @"[January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December]\s\d+,\s\d+");
string date = match.Groups[1].Value;
string blah = yourstring.Substring(0, yourstring.IndexOf(date) -1);
```

Comment: Not working for this string for example "A Truly Relatable and Actionable Guide to Customer Service, May 29, 2012", Tnx anyway

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression such as:

```
.*,(.*,\s*\d+)$
```

This will create a match group for:

```
June 19, 2011
```

It would match any characters followed by a comma followed by a number followed by the end of the string.

[Example](http://www.rubular.com/r/aittrCzpM2)